# SQL Query for finding duplicate, and then select one of the record among them

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query. I want to check if I have any duplicate for a SNO+SG Combination. If a duplicate record like that is found, we select the one which is not having the flag Y.(we dont want to select the record where Flag column is filled for that duplicate combination).
This should be followed only when a duplicate combination is found.
I have attached a sample input and output over here:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtUnX.png)

Can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sno, sg order by (flag = 'Y') desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by sno, sg) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1 and seqnum = 1;
```